# Magento: compressing image not working effectively in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, gzip, pagespeed

I have the version 1.7.0.2 of magneto.I have enabled the gzip compression css htaccess js and css compression showing 100% on web page test org http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140812_2H_JQX/ but the problem is that image compression is only 38% i just want increase image compression.

I tried lots of code and extensions but not getting any improvement on image compression.

Any one can tell me how can i compress the image via .htaccess or using any extensions.

I am using bellow code in htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip
    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript

    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html


    # Don't compress images
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is; You're not going to find a method to easily compress images properly using only `.htaccess`.

If you want compression levels similar to the PageSpeed plugin you might want to put your attention to the following documentation:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?hl=fr#CompressImages

**Method 1**

I'm going to take a guess and assume the plugins you tried to use either not doing what they advertise (it happens with Magento community plugins) or used a tool you either didn't have installed or needed to install, but this is the automatic method.

In the linked article under "**Use an image compressor**" there are several tools outlined which can be used to compress images on linux environments. You could build a Magento plugin to automate that process. Short of that there isn't anything to do this easily.

**Method 2**

What you can do however is have the images which PageSpeed optimizes be saved in a configured directory. Now the link for that is broken but you can find that here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages

After running PageSpeed you can then just upload the images to their respective directories.

I would suggest the second method, as the first method isn't exactly easy and requires you to be able to control the live hosting environment to install plugins/tools you need.

Also, don't bite down on PageSpeed scores too much, seeing that report makes me wonder how many plugins you installed on Magento that are now causing a lot of overhead. Note that any plugin slows down Magento a bit, and it's not fast in and on itself either, so other methods / caching are way more valuable than micro-managing image sizes. Time to first byte is easier to optimize than image compression.

Comment: all the installed plugin i needed i cant avoid this i am on shared hosting is there any chance with mod page speed installation to solve image optimization problem

Comment: If mod_pagespeed is used you can do it with htaccess, but please mind that the use of mod_pagespeed also has a certain overhead. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-image-optimize So in your htaccess put `ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images` and it should resize your images.

Comment: In that case mod_pagespeed is probably not installed. Please note that your webhost would need to install and run mod_pagespeed for that option to be viable, but the average shared host won't have that.